# It doesn't append as floating Python | Problem #18

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, isinteger

I'm writing this code for [the problem #18](https://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/square-root) in Codeabbey. I need to calculate the square root of an array of numbers `[150, 0, 5, 1 10, 3]` I have to divide this array in three arrays (x,n) `[[150, 0], [5, 1], [10 3]]` where x: is the number I want to calculate the square root of and n: is the number of times I have to try the formula r = (r + x / r) / 2 to get the result which is r, r is starting with 1. There's no problem with that, the problem is when I have to append the result because if r is `3.0` I have to append it as an integer: `3` but if r is `3.964` I have to append it as a floating.

```
def squareRoot():
    rawArr = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
    arr = [rawArr[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(rawArr)-1,2)]
    results = []

    for a in arr:
        x,n = a
        r = 1.0
        for i in range(0,n):
            r = (r + x / r) / 2
        if r.is_integer:
            results.append(str(int(r)))
        else:
            results.append(str(round(r,3)))
    return " ".join(results)
```

The input is:

```
150 0 5 1 10 3
```

and the output is:

```
'1 3 3'
```

This is what I get if I don't use is_integer():

```
'1 3.0 3.196xxxxx'
```

What the output should be:

```
1 3 3.196
```

I can't see where the problem is.

Comment: Instead of rounding off, have you tried changing the precision?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I don't know how to do that

Comment: Use ```isinstance()``` to check if the variable is an int or float.

Comment: Please read the documentation on ```isinstance()```; Use it like ```if isinstance(r, int):```

Comment: @AbhinavMathur if I use ```isintance(r, int)``` I get ```1 3 3```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_integer` is a method you run on `float` type. You forgot to invoke it, so it evaluates to `True` as it returns a builtin which is something (not nothing).

Just replace

```
        if r.is_integer:
```

with

```
        if r.is_integer():
```

Comment: Oh, crap! Thank you very much!